# Can I use finally statement with def statement?

Tags: python

I'm creating a program and I was wondering, is there way to use `finally` with `def` statement? For example:

```
# NOT WORKING
def test(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c
finally:
    del a,b,c

x = test(4,5,6)
```

so I can delete variables in function after `return` in function, or do I need to delete variables after calling the function?

EDIT: It was stupid example with variables but I wanted to achive not only deleting variables (as I was thinking it stay in RAM until delete), but also deleting files and similar.

The code that helped me with it is:

```
def test(a, b, c):
    try:
        return a + b + c
    finally:
        pass # do whatever you want
```

Comment: 1. No, there isn't; and 2. what do you mean *"delete variables in function"*? What do you actually want to *achieve?!*

Comment: You can't use `finally` with `def`. Moreover, you don't need to delete variables (I guess you're trying to do so to deallocate memory?) Python has garbage collector.

Comment: @sobolevn There are uses for `del`, but this is not one of them. In this example the variables goes out of scope automatically. If that didn't happen you might want to use `del` to remove the bindings from scope (that doesn't have to mean to remove the objects). For example if you no longer want `x` to be a global variable anymore you'd use `del` (and maybe the object that was named `x` could be destroyed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete variables in python. I'm not sure if you're coming from some weird language or are asking something different. But there is a way to achieve what you want by putting a `try` inside the function:

```
def test(a, b, c):
    try:
        return a + b + c
    finally:
        pass # do whatever you want
```

But regular variables can just be forgotten when they go out of scope. With resources like files you would [use `with` instead](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open('blah.txt', 'rb') as f:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about deleting you should ask yourself that delete from where? any python object exist within a namespace (global,local,built-in,...) and in this case  your variables inside function are in a local namespace and if you don't want to use them inside the function you don't need to delete them, you can simply delete your function.

But if you have defined your variables in global namespace deleting the variables inside function doesn't delete them in global namespace, you can delete them after calling the function.

example :

```
>>> def a(x,y):
...   return x,y
... 
>>> a(3,4)
(3, 4)
>>> del a
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

And if you defined the variables outside the function :

```
>>> x,y=3,9
>>> def a(x,y):
...   del x,y
...   print x
... 
>>> a(x,y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in a
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>> x
3
```